# Install flatpak on Redhat

Tags: rhel, flatpak

All the existing links on the internet talk about how to install flatpak, and then how to add the flathub repo and install apps.

For me, this command doesn't work:

```
$ sudo yum install flatpak
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite
No package flatpak available
Error: nothing to do
```

I have tried adding `epel`, `ELRepo` and `Remi` repos but no good. How to get flatpak? or is that dead?

Comment: If you are using RedHat Enterprise Linux 7, then you should have access to https://access.redhat.com/, look for the package browser/search and that should tell you which subscriptions are necessary to install `flatpak`.  If you are using RedHat EL 6, I do not think `flatpak` is available for that version.